# VS 2010 Ultimate web load test failure - Always critical processor time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, web

I am trying to test a web application. So I have recorded very simple scenario (single page with only one label) and created counter for processor time with 30 as warning threshold and 60 as critical threshold value. When I run the test, system's CPU processor is almost 90% for all requests. I tried with 10, 5, 1 concurrent users for 2 minutes. I couldn't get the result.

Let me know if I miss anything. How to run load test properly.

Thanks in Advance.